# CompletableFuture.allOf cancel other futures when one throws exception

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

Java 8's [`CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture<?>...cfs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) will return a `CompletableFuture` that is completed when all the given futures complete, or throws a `CompletionException` if one of the futures completes with an exception.

If one of my futures completes with an exception, will `CompletableFuture.allOf` wait for the remaining futures to complete before throwing the `CompletionException` or will it cancel the remaining futures?

If it waits for all futures to complete, it there any way to make it return immediately when any future throws an exception and cancel the remaining futures?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If one of my futures completes with an exception, will `CompletableFuture.allOf` wait for the remaining futures to complete before throwing the `CompletionException`

Yes, it will still wait for all the futures to complete.

You could use this helper method to create a `CompletableFuture` which completes exceptionally once any of the futures does so.

```
public static CompletableFuture allOfTerminateOnFailure(CompletableFuture<?>... futures) {
    CompletableFuture<?> failure = new CompletableFuture();
    for (CompletableFuture<?> f: futures) {
        f.exceptionally(ex -> {
            failure.completeExceptionally(ex);
            return null;
        });
    }
    return CompletableFuture.anyOf(failure, CompletableFuture.allOf(futures));
}
```

If you also want to cancel all other futures if one of them completes exceptionally, you could do it like this before returning from this method:

```
failure.exceptionally(ex -> {
    Arrays.stream(futures).forEach(f -> f.cancel(true));
    return null;
});
```

Comment: Is it also possible to call `cancel(true)` on all of the futures inside `f.exceptionally()`? I would assume that it will also work, since we are saying that on an exception, we want all futures to cancel. But I guess this will result in redundant `cancel` calls?

Comment: @mnestorov yes, it's possible to call it from there, and you are right, it will result in extra `cancel` calls.